# What happens to bardic inspiration if either the bard or the recipient of the inspiration dies/goes unconscious?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, unconscious

In D&D 5e, a bard can give Bardic Inspiration - a d6-d12, depending on the level of the bard - which can be used by the recipient to add to a single ability check, attack roll, or saving throw within 10 minutes of getting the Bardic Inspiration die.

What happens to this Bardic Inspiration die when the bard goes unconscious/dies, or the character who received the inspiration goes unconscious?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Nothing, it's still there.

Long story short, there's nothing in the rules for Bardic Inspiration that says it goes away if either the giver or the recipient is rendered unconscious or slain. One of the core rules is "Specific Beats General", and in this case, there is no General that says the dice would go away. There's nothing RAW stopping you from being slain, raised by a quick Revivify, and still having the dice.

And if you need an explanation for why you are still inspired by the bard you just saw turned into a pointy metal object repository, their words and music inspired you so much you're now doubly moved to avenge them.